# How do you snapshot a cloudbees mysql database via the api/SDK?

Tags: mysql, cloudbees

I would like to take snapshots of my cloudbees mysql database via the command line (for example, to snapshot before I deploy a destructive update).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Cloudbees SDK](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK)

```
 bees db:snapshot:create [options] DATABASE_NAME
```

also

```
bees db:snapshot:list [options] DATABASE_NAME
```

To restore to a given snapshot:

```
bees db:snapshot:deploy [options] DATABASE_NAME SNAPSHOT_ID
```